# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in jest mount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to mock a component using Mount when I run the test I am getting error as

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Jest:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);    
    store = createStore(combineReducers({ clerks: clerkReducer }), middleware);
    console.log('store is', store);

    wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ClerksList {...props} dispatch={mockDispatchfn} />
        </Provider>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );
});
```

code:

```
props.dispatch(fetchClerks()).then(() => {
  setLoading(false);
});
```

Action Call:

```
const fetchClerks = (): any => {
  const clerks = store.getState().clerks;
  const params = {
    page: clerks.currentPage,
    perPage: clerks.perPage,
  };
  return (dispatch: Dispatch): Promise<any> =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dispatch(fetchClerksStart());
      http
        .get('/v1/clerks', { params })
        .then((response: any) => {
          if (response) {
            const clerksResponse = {
              currentPage: response.currentPage,
              data: response.clerks,
              isFirstPage: response.isFirstPage,
              isLastPage: response.isLastPage,
              nextPage: response.nextPage,
              perPage: response.perPage,
              prevPage: response.prevPage,
              totalCount: response.totalCount,
              totalPages: response.totalPages,
            };
            dispatch(fetchClerksSuccess(clerksResponse));
          }
          resolve('clerks fetched');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error.message);
          dispatch(fetchClerksFailure());
        });
    });
};
```

Though i have checked similar issues in stackoverflow but there it has been mentioned as the action should retun. Though i am returning the action call. I don't know what is wrong

Comment: I'm not familiar with this too much, but looking at the function, props.dispatch needs to return a promise for this to work, not fetchClerks, right?

Comment: @JonathanM.Hethey but the fetchClerks returns the promise then why we need to return props.dispatch

Comment: `fetchClerks` does not return a promise, it returns a *function*.

Comment: Hi @Nidhinkumar, can you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) where the error you are experiencing is reproducible? In that manner, it will be easier to help you!

Comment: @Sulthan then what to do to return a promise instead of function